# Having difficulty setting up git push/pull

Tags: git

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSION
```

What does this mean? It sounds like I have a remote branch but it's not correctly hooked up to the remote repository.
This used to work on a different branch.

I keep getting errors when I try to set it up.

```
>git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSI
ON EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSION
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSION' does not
exist
hint:
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint:
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

I try to run git fetch but it doesn't tell me what's going on.
I can see the branch online in my web browser.

```
>git branch --v
* EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSION              d53eae9 EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSIOn started
 testing hash code
 ...other branches
```

I noticed that the upstream is mispelled. There is an undercase n. Maybe that's causing it? How do I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, this is a case sensitivity issue. Git is case sensitive on case-sensitive filesystems.

To rename the remote branch to be correct (by tracking, deleting and re-pushing it), run the following:

```
$ git branch EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSION origin/EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSIOn
$ git push origin --set-upstream EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSION
$ git push origin :EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSIOn
```

Or if you already have an up-to-date local branch under the correct name, just delete the remote branch and re-push:

```
$ git push origin --set-upstream EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSION
$ git push origin :EXP-20-DOMAIN-CONVERSIOn
```

Comment: Thanks. It works!

I see that I wasn't setting my upstream correctly earlier